# Why can't we assimilate the predicates number? and same-variable? into the data-directed dispatch?

Tags: functional-programming, polymorphism, scheme, sicp

In exercise 2.73 from [section 2.4.3](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-17.html#%25_sec_2.4.3), the following code is shown:

```lisp
(define (deriv exp var)
   (cond ((number? exp) 0)
         ((variable? exp) (if (same-variable? exp var) 1 0))
         (else ((get 'deriv (operator exp)) (operands exp)
                                            var))))
(define (operator exp) (car exp))
(define (operands exp) (cdr exp))
```

which makes use of *data-directed dispatch*, assuming that for each operator `op` that one can possibly find in the input `exp`, an appropriate function `f` has been installed in a table via `put 'deriv op f`.

The first question about this exercise is the following

> a. […] Why can't we assimilate the predicates `number?` and `variable?` into the data-directed dispatch?

where the two predicates refer to the "old" implementation of `deriv`, which uses the following instead of the `else` branch above:

```lisp
        ((sum? exp)
         (make-sum (deriv (addend exp) var)
                   (deriv (augend exp) var)))
        ((product? exp)
         (make-sum
           (make-product (multiplier exp)
                         (deriv (multiplicand exp) var))
           (make-product (deriv (multiplier exp) var)
                         (multiplicand exp))))
        ; more rules can be added here
        (else (error "unknown expression type -- DERIV" exp))))
```

My question is *why can't I?*

The proposed implementation of `operator` and `operands` is simple and assumes that an operator is present and that is the first in the list representing the expression `exp`, so I can't hope to make the "assimilation" without changing them.

But what if I do change them?

I could define them like so,

```lisp
(define (operator e)
  (cond ((pair? e) (car e))
        ((number? e) 'number)
        (else 'variable)))

(define (operands e)
  (cond ((pair? e) (cdr e))
        (else e))) ; maybe `e` -> `cons e '()`, not sure
```

deciding that if the expression `e` is not a pair, then *it is* its own operands, the operator being the literal `'number` or `'variable` as appropriate.

Then I could install the needed procedures under `'deriv`-`'number` and  `'deriv`-`'variable`.

---

The procedures `put` and `get` are defined in [3.3.3](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sites/default/files/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-22.html#%25_sec_3.3.3), and I'm trying not to step ahead of myself, so I've not yet looked into that, hence I haven't tried testing my hypothesis as I described above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write that, but you haven't really assimilated into the data-directed approach. You've just moved the special-casing for `number?` and `variable?` into a different function. I think the text is asking you why you can't uniformly dispatch on `operator` without any special cases, and the answer is because your representation does not define an operator for numbers or variables.

If I were going to try to make this representation more uniform, I would define a constructor `make-number` such that `(make-number 6)` yields something tagged as a number, such as `'(number . 6)`, and likewise for variables. *Then* you could install handlers for those tags, and just look at the operator of each datum, because each datum will really have an operator.

Comment: Why that `.` in `'(number . 6)`?

Comment: @Enlico by William of Ockham's famous saying, "cons cells should not be multiplied beyond necessity". `(a . b)` is `(cons a b)` whereas `(a b)` is `(cons a (cons b '()))`.